# Trying to create an interactive hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a hamburger menu. This is my progress so far:
http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/EgAdLN

```html
<div class="bar"></div> 
    <nav>
        <ul role="navigation" class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">RESUME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```js
( function () {

    $('.hamburger-menu').on('click', function() {

        $( '.bar' ).toggleClass( 'animate' );
        $( '.bar' ).toggleClass( "on" );
        $( "nav ul" ).toggleClass( 'hidden' );

    } );

} )();
```

```css
/* SCSS */
@import "compass/css3";

$bar-width: 50px;
$bar-height: 4px;
$bar-spacing: 15px;

body {
    background: #000000;
}

.hamburger-menu {
    position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: $bar-width;
    height: $bar-height + $bar-spacing*2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar,
.bar:after,
.bar:before {
  width: $bar-width;
    height: $bar-height;
}

.bar {
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY($bar-spacing);
    background: rgba(155, 255, 255, 1);
    transition: all 0ms 300ms;

  &.animate {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
  }
}

.bar:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: $bar-spacing;
    background: rgba(155, 255, 255, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.bar:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: $bar-spacing;
    background: rgba(155, 255, 255, 1);
    transition: top 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.bar.animate:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
}

.bar.animate:before {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
}

nav ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 4em auto;
  text-align: center;

  &.hidden {
    display: none;
  }

    a {
    @include transition-duration(0.5s);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
      &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      }
    }
}
```

I have been bolting together a few bits of code I like with mixed success.

I want to create something like: https://bert.house/en/

But what I am having issues with, is that when I click on any of my navigation links it closes the menu. Also I am unsure how to get my menu to appear in the centre of the screen over everything else (like on the bert website). I also am unsure how to create the vanishing MENU word at the right side of the burger menu on the bert site.

I am pretty new to this, my html experience prior to this has been building emails rather than actual websites. So any help would be brilliant.

Comment: Have you ever used the Developer Tools in Google Chrome or Firefox? It is a great tool to inspect the code (HTML, CSS, JS) of others and learn how to build certain features.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I have now managed to decipher some of how they built it from using this.

Answer (score 1):

### 1) *"My navigation links it closes the menu"*

That's because your navigation links are inside of `.hamburger-menu`. The click handler you attached to `.hamburger-menu` will receive the click event form any element nested within it unless that even is canceled.

To fix this do one of the following:

1. Move the menu outside of `.hamburger-menu`.
2. Cancel the event before it reaches `.hamburger-menu`. Use `event.preventDefault()`.
3. Check the source element of the click event and make sure it came from `.hamburger-menu` and not an element nested within it. Use `event.target`.

### 2) *"how to get my menu to appear in the center of the screen"*

You can use absolute positioning and translation. First you tell it to be 50% from the top of the containing overlay element. Then you nudge the navigation up by 50% of it's height with translation. You do this because `top: 50%;` places the top edge of the navigation in the middle of the overlay rather than the middle of the navigation in the middle of the overly.

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Something for you to look at.
</p>

<div class="overlay">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### 3) *"I also am unsure how to create the vanishing MENU word"*

You need to transition the element's `opacity`, set it to zero. The text also shifts to the side a little bit so animate it along it's X axis with `translateX()`.

For example:

```
.text {
    transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
    transform: translateX( 0 );
}
.show .text {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX( -10px );
}
```

### JS Notes

jQuery is chainable so can change:

```
$( '.bar' ).toggleClass( 'animate' );
$( '.bar' ).toggleClass( "on" );
```

to

```
$( '.bar' ).toggleClass( 'animate' ).toggleClass( "on" );
```

You can also provide more than once class to `toggleClass` so you can change:

```
$( '.bar' ).toggleClass( 'animate' ).toggleClass( "on" );
```

to

```
$( '.bar' ).toggleClass( 'animate on' );
```

I personally like to cache elements so I don't have to query the DOM every time a certain click event happens so I would do something like this:

```js
( function () {

    var $bar   = $( '.bar' );
    var $navUL = $( 'nav ul' );

    $( '.hamburger-menu' ).on( 'click', function () {

        $bar.toggleClass( 'animate on' );
        $navUL.toggleClass( 'hidden' );

    } );

} )();
```

You likely won't notice a difference in performance on your site but I think it's good practice for situations when you should/need to cache references to elements.

Comment: Thank you thats some great advice. I have not worked out all of it yet, but I have gotten at least part of the way there.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/EgAdLN not sure how to edit comments... But here is my progress so far. Still need to work through all your advice. Might need to ask you another question or two later. But for the moment thank you again!

Comment: .hamburger-menu .text {
    margin-left: 60px;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.show .text {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX( -10px );
}

Comment: Okay.... was not supposed to post that or like that. But I can't seem to delete comments. Or write this in the same way as a normal post..... Basically I have applied the code you mentioned to get the word "MENU" to slide off to the right and vanish when you click on it, but for some reason I cannot get it working. Have I missed something?

Comment: The selector I provided was `.show .text`, notice the space between the classes. `.show` is a class that you apply to a parent/ancestor element of `.text` not to the same element. `.show` is a class that should be added/removed when the menu icon is clicked.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/EgAdLN Ah I believe I have figured it out, though I have gotten it back to front....But it's a start! Thank you again!

Comment: @Schro you're making harder than it has to be. No need for extra elements. Just apply a class, **doesn't have to be** `.show`, to a parent/ancestor element of the element containing the text MENU. In fact, you don't need `.show` **and** `.animate`. They're both a class indicating a state so one of them can go. I removed `.animate` and made the code work with only `.show`. Take a look at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjGxjA).

Comment: That is a much neater solution. Didn't realise I could use the same JS var for everything in the menu. Sorry if it seems I am picking up your advice slow. Thank you again.

Comment: You will get sick of me soon I bet. A couple more questions, if I want to add other divs and elements to the overlay. Like say contact information. What would be the best way to do it? I though if I applied the "overlay" class in the CSS to a new contacts class that it would apply it to the same area. Though that does not seem to work ( http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/zKXARr ), also on another point I think I have done something wrong in regards to getting my links to centre on the overlay.